# Using TreeMap to find max elements

Tags: java, data-structures, heap, time-complexity, treemap

I am designing a Baseball League scoreboard of TOP 5 Batsmen. I am using a `TreeMap` with *player_name* as `value` and `Player` as `key`.

```
Map<Player, String> players  = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

`Player` class has natural ordering as per runs scored in the league
`compare(this.leagueRuns, otherPlayer.leagueRuns)`

`leagueRuns` are updated contantly during the game and the TOP 5 Batsmen scoreboard should also change accordingly. Below is the code to update league runs for a player and re-insertion into `TreeMap`. After updating, TOP 5 entries from Map are retrieved and displayed.

```
 public void updateRuns(String playerName, int runsScored) {

            Iterator<Entry<Player, String>> playersEntries = players.entrySet().iterator();

            Player player = null;
            while (playersEntries.hasNext()) {
                Entry<Player, String> currentPlayer = playersEntries.next();
                if (currentPlayer.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(playerName)) {
                    player = currentPlayer.getKey();
                }
            }
            players.remove(player);
            player.addRuns(runsScored);
            players.put(player, player.getName());        
 }
```

Everything is working fine but I have following concerns:

1. In order to sort `Player` I am using it as `Key` in `TreeMap`. But have to iterate through the whole `Map` to find `Player` being updated. Hence time complexity degraded from O(1) to O(n). And gets even worse as I have to remove that `Player`, update it and re-insert otherwise changes won't take effect. Hence `O(n + logn)`. Is there a way to sort `Player` as per natural ordering and also be able to search in O(1). I guess re-insertion cannot be avoided.
2. Every time `leagueRuns` is updated for a player, the whole `TreeMap` has to be re-ordered. Do you think creating a separate min-heap of TOP 5 Batsmen can resolve this issue and is a viable idea.
3. Any tips on design or improving time complexity.

Comment: @DavidWallace Searching & Updating a `Player` can be done in O(1) using `HashMap<String, Player>. But overall cost ofconstructing a separate list of max scorers will be O(nlogn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should support 2 structures:

1. quick player search (name => Player), e.g. HashMap<String, Player>
2. sorted structure for scoreboard (Player & score), e.g. TreeSet<Player>

So update scoreboard will be O(log(N)):

```
Map<String, Player> players;
SortedSet<Player> scoreboard;

public void updateRuns(String playerName, int runsScored) {
    Player player = players.get(playerName);
    if (player == null) {
        player = new Player(playerName, runsScored);
    } else {
        scorepoard.remove(player);
        player.addRuns(runsScored);
    }
    scoreboard.add(player);
}
```

If you make Player class unmodifiable (preferred way), you'll get the same O(log(N)):

```
public void updateRuns(String playerName, int runsScored) {
    Player player = players.remove(playerName);
    if (player == null) {
        player = new Player(playerName, runsScored);
    } else {
        scorepoard.remove(player);
        player = new Player(playerName, player.getRuns() + runsScored);
    }
    players.put(playerName, player);
    scoreboard.add(player);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, and the only really sensible way of doing it.  +1.

Comment: Wondering if (number of players) is large say > 10^6. Keeping `Player` object in both data structures` would lead to data redundancy.

Comment: Actually there is no data duplication. Data structures are required to keep only the **structure** for fast access. If you have 10^6 players, you will have in memory 10^6 Player entries + HashMap(N=10^6) structure + TreeSet(N=10^6) structure.